# SQL queries through PYODBC fail silently on one machine, works on another

Tags: python, sql, database, pyodbc

I am working on a program to automate parsing data from XML files and storing it into several databases.  (Specifically the USGS realtime water quality service, if anyone's interested, at http://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/WaterML-Interim-REST-Service.html)  It's written in Python 2.5.1 using LXML and PYODBC. The databases are in Microsoft Access 2000.

The connection function is as follows:
    def get_AccessConnection(db):
        connString = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=' + db
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connString, autocommit=False)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        return cnxn, cursor
where db is the filepath to the database.

The program:
a) opens the connection to the database
b) parses 2 to 8 XML files for that database and builds the values from them into a series of records to insert into the database (using a nested dictionary structure, not a user-defined type)
c) loops through the series of records, cursor.execute()-ing an SQL query for each one
d) commits and closes the database connection

If the cursor.execute() call throws an error, it writes the traceback and the query to the log file and moves on.

When my coworker runs it on his machine, for one particular database, specific records will simply not be there, with no errors recorded.  When I run the exact same code on the exact same copy of the database over the exact same network path from my machine, all the data that should be there is there.

My coworker and I are both on Windows XP computers with Microsoft Access 2000 and the same versions of Python, lxml, and pyodbc installed.  I have no idea how to check whether we have the same version of the Microsoft ODBC drivers.  I haven't been able to find any difference between the records that are there and the records that aren't.  I'm in the process of testing whether the same problem happens with the other databases, and whether it happens on a third coworker's computer as well.

What I'd really like to know is ANYTHING anyone can think of that would cause this, because it doesn't make sense to me.  To summarize: Python code executing SQL queries will silently fail half of them on one computer and work perfectly on another.

Edit:
No more problem.  I just had my coworker run it again, and the database was updated completely with no missing records. Still no idea why it failed in the first place, nor whether or not it will happen again, but "problem solved."

Comment: Does it make any difference without `autocommit`? Access is not a transactional database so certainly `autocommit= False` cannot be honoured. All my experiences of talking to Access via scripts with ODBC have been absolutely awful (hangs, etc). You could try ADO which is at least less bad... ideally of course Access needs to go away.

Comment: I had no idea Access wasn't transactional.  It's certainly behaved as such -- if I didn't call cnxn.commit() while I was testing the program, no changes to the databases would persist.

I would rather not change autocommit if possible. I don't want half-finished databases if an unexpected and unhandled error comes up.

Comment: @Rowan: This is expected, Access waits to do anything till you tell it to commit -- in this way it "honors" the transaction.  :( -> Access

Comment: @bobince re: *"Access is not a transactional database so certainly autocommit= False cannot be honoured."* - Absolute rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea how to check whether
>   we have the same version of the
>   Microsoft ODBC drivers.

I think you're looking for Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Data Sources (ODBC). Click the "Drivers" tab.

I think either Access 2000 or Office 2000 shipped with a desktop edition of SQL Server called "MSDE". Might be worth installing that for testing. (Or production, for that matter.)